# How to store a custom attr to order when you hit "Place order" button in magento 1.9

Tags: checkout, custom, custom-attributes

I am looking for a solution with my magento order sales problem. I added to order a attribute which one I want to set on event sales_order_place_after. Attribute is added and seted correctly. When I hit button "Place Order" and order has been received I want to look about this order in Admin dashboard(Seles->Orders). In grid I find a column "Action" and click "View" link. Where are information about Account I would like my custom attr be showen.

my mysql4-upgrade file look like this:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_attr', array(
'input' => 'text',
'type' => 'varchar',
'label' => 'Sub user email',
'visible' => true,
'required' => true,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'user_defined' => true
));

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

config.xml

```
  <checkout_submit_all_after>
    <observers>
      <mymodule_sales_order_place_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>saveCustomAttribute</method>
      </mymodule_sales_order_place_after>
    </observers>
  </checkout_submit_all_after>
```

and saveCustomAttribute function in Observer:

```
     public function saveCustomAttribute($observer)
     {
       # code...
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $order->setCustomAttr('dummy@dummy.com');
     }

  }
```

I am new to Magento. Hope that I described well my problem.